# Method comment syntax check fails in Intellij Idea

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

```
     /**
     * @param m_type
     *            the m_type to set
     */
```

This method comment automatically created in Eclipse generates a syntactic error in Idea. I have to remove one '*' symbol from '**'. Is this normal?

Comment: Could you show us the "syntactic error in Idea"? What is the error **message**?

Comment: Does the method have a parameter *m_type*? Please show the next line with the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can override the template

Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates -> Comments -> Methods and click Edit

Comment: This is in Intellij's Idea, not in Eclipse.

Comment: You wrote 'This method comment automatically created in Eclipse'